# ¿Como recorro y comparo un array de tres dimensiones?

Tags: javascript, array, array-bidimensional

Tengo este array:

```js
var elarray = [
  [['1','3','5' ],['8','9','6' ],['3','0','4' ],['7','6','5' ], ['3','4','0' ], ['1','7','6' ], ['1','1','1' ], ['1','3','2' ], ['2','3','3' ], ['3','0','5' ], ['4','7','6' ], ['5','9','8' ], ['9','1','7' ], ['4','8','6' ], ['7','0','3' ], ['4','4','4' ], ['4','1','9' ], ['7','5','1' ], ['4','3','3' ], ['1','5','8' ]],
  [['8','9','6' ],['3','0','4' ],['7','6','5' ],['2','3','3' ], ['3','0','5' ], ['4','7','6' ], ['5','9','8' ],  ['4','8','6' ], ['7','0','3' ], ['4','4','4' ], ['4','1','9' ], ['1','3','1' ], ['4','1','9' ], ['7','5','1' ],['1','1','1' ], ['1','3','2' ], ['2','3','3' ], ['3','0','5' ], ['4','7','6' ], ['5','9','8' ]],
  [ ['1','3','2' ], ['2','3','3' ], ['3','0','5' ], ['4','7','6' ], ['5','9','8' ], ['9','1','7' ], ['4','8','6' ], ['7','0','3' ], ['4','4','4' ], ['4','1','9' ], ['7','5','1' ], ['4','3','3' ], ['1','5','8' ],['4','8','6' ], ['7','0','3' ], ['4','4','4' ], ['4','1','9' ], ['1','1','1' ], ['4','1','9' ], ['7','5','1' ]]
  ];
```

Necesito recorrerlo e ir comparando por ejemplo si `elarray[0][0][0][0]` es igual a `elarray[0][1][0][0]`, o si es igual a `elarray[0][2][0][0]` y así consecutivamente...

Comment: si tienes un array de 4 dimensiones, entonces recorrelo  con 4 `for`s o `while`s

Comment: No entiendo cuál es el error ni tampoco el objetivo final de hacer esta pregunta.

Comment: Hola , no hay un error solo no se como poder recorrer los arrays y poder comparar los elementos en cada posicion y saber si son iguales , como si estuviese comparando 3 arrays diferentes..., saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de nada no recomiendo anidar más de 2 dimensiones de arrays, pero la respuesta a tu pregunta sería la siguiente:

```js
for(var i=0; i<nuevoArray.length; i++) {
    for(var n=0; n<nuevoArray[i].length; n++) {
        for(var j=0; j<nuevoArray[i][n].length; j++) {
              document.write(nuevoArray[i][n][j]);
              //tu codigo
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola , gracias por la respuesta , entiendo como recorrerlo , pero mi problema es como hago para recorrerlo y poder comparar con un if los 3 elementos de cada posicion de cada array y saber si son iguales o no , tal vez me explique mal en la consigna , saludos